# Get data to Parent component from multi child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to collect data from all child components and get it in Parent component. 
   For example i have a form component with "Save" button.
   Once i click on "Save" button i need all child component send me all data that an user put there.

```
<Form>
  <Name />
  <DatePicker />
  .....
</Form>
```

So the main component is Form and it has several child components. Once i click on "Save" in  i need to get child components data in Form.

**I am thinking about giving "ref" to all child component** and call their own methods in Parent once i click on "Save" inside Form. In those methods i will collect all data and fire events with **this.$emit** there i can send to parent the data i have collected.

Is that a good solution?

Or maybe better to use EventBus?

Comment: I wrote a related article a few minutes ago. You need the child components to $emit their changes to the parent component: https://dev.to/valentinprgnd/wrap-a-text-field-in-a-component-with-vue-js-gak

Comment: I see. So the main point is this.$watch and using it we follow the changes and notify parent about that.

Comment: But my case is a bit complex. I need to get info from child components only when i click on "Save" button in parent component. So child components should not pass any data until parent tells them about it

Comment: Do you have a Form component in whose slot you give other components, e.g. Name, DatePicker, and you want the data from these subcomponents to go to this Form after pressing Save? Using multiple Form components with different subcomponents results in separate data sets in each Form?

Comment: I don't use slots.
I have 1 form parent component with 7 child components inside. And yes, after pressing "Save" in Form component i need to get all data from all child components inside Form component....

Comment: Do you have to do it this way because that's the design assumption?
or
Do you want to do it this way because you have no idea how to do it differently?

Comment: @Gander well, imagine please, a big modal window with a lot of different controls such as, 1 input, 2 datepickers there i can choose DateFrom and DateTo (vuejs-datepicker) and some additional select controls. 
So i decided to divide all these controls inside separate components in order to handle them in an easier way.
   In general this modal window is for creating an Event like Google calendar has, so i show this modal and an user can choose "Event name", "Event date (from and to), guests select box, meeting type select and so on.

Comment: @Gander So user can pick all data that is needed and press "Save button" in modal window and based on all data i have to create EVENT. And i am thinking how to gather all data from parent components once i click on "Save button" in parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer `bind` over `emit`.

```js
Vue.component("InputField", {
  template: `<input v-model="syncedValue" />`,
  name: "InputField",
  props: {
    value: String
  },
  computed: {
    syncedValue: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("input", v);
      }
    }
  }
});

Vue.component("Form", {
  template: `<div><InputField v-model="name"/><InputField v-model="surname"/><button @click="save">Save</button></div>`,
  name: "Form",
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      surname: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      alert(`${this.name} ${this.surname}`);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  template: `<Form></Form>`
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I know that the component code is similar to use with bidirectional binding to the `.sync` modifier but the `v-model` is more readable for me in this situation

Comment: thank you for you help.
But what if i have "datepicker" component like this:

       <DatePicker :dateFrom="dateFrom" :dateTo="dateTo"  />

And this datepicker inside it has 2 vuejs-datepickers, and 4 input fields. So this component is being used to pick any FROM date+time and TO date+time.
So i can't use v-model for it as i understood.

Comment: I tried to add .sync:
<DatePicker :dateFrom.sync="dateFrom" :dateTo.sync="dateTo" ref="datePicker" />

But even if i change dateTo inside <DatePicker" in child component it is still without changing...

Comment: Well, i found only one way: to emit events once data has been changed in child components and catch that event in Parent component and update the state there. But since i have a chain of 3 or more components inside each other i would use EventBus for that.